# Show that this set of functions are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $\{\cos{x},\sin{x},\cos{2x}, \sin{2x},\cdots\}\cup\{1\}\cup\{e^{\cos x}\}$.

I was able to show that the first two sets are linearly independent (there are many solutions out there as well) but I am stuck in showing the independence of the last set. I tried to assume that they are linearly dependent such that

$$0=a_0+ \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx+ c_n e^{\cos x} $$ for some coefficients $a_i,b_i,c_i$. Can anyone give me some hints on this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you considering this set of functions as defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier series? When you say "integrate the the thing", do you mean that you were trying to compute the series coefficients?

Comment: @GReyes No. It was supposed to be just on $[0,2\pi]$. But this function is periodic so it doesn’t matter ain’t it?

Comment: Agree. Id does not matter. You should try to prove that the Fourier coefficients are non-zero for any $n$, or at least for some infinite subset of indices.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry, I am not up to Fourier series yet. By integration I mean I was trying to integrate two sides to make some terms to be $0$ but it seems it’s not working..

Comment: Play with Wronskians? You'll have three cases to look at: 1) $1$ and $e^{\cos x}$ do not participate; 2) $1$ participates and $e^{\cos x}$ does not; 3) $e^{\cos x}$ participates and $1$ does not. You'll have to find $x_0$ for which the determinant of derivatives does not vanish. Of course, here I'm using that an infinite set is linearly independent if every finite subset is linearly independent.

Comment: @Edi Could you give us some context for the question then? Is this an assigned question from a course you're taking? If so, then what are some tools from this course that my apply here? For instance, have you discussed Wronskians?

Comment: @GReyes unfortunately my class haven’t covered Fourier series yet. Is there any other way to prove the independence or how should I do that? Thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A complex analytic proof:  From the formulas for $\cos (2x), \cos (3x)$ etc we can write $e^{\cos x}=p(\cos x)$ for some polynomial $p$. It follows that the entire functions $e^{z}$ and $p$ coincide on a set with a limit point. By the Identity Theorem we see that $e^{z}=p(z)$ for all $z$ which is a contradiction (For example,  LHS has no zeros).

Second proof: As mentioned above it is a well known fact that $\cos (nx) $ can be expressed as a polynomial in $\cos x$. Hence we get $e^{\cos x} =\sum_{i=0}^{m} b_i \cos^{i}x$ for some $m$ and some coefficients $b_i$. This gives $e^{t}= \sum_{i=0}^{m} b_i t^{i}$ for $-1 \leq t \leq 1$.  Now differentiate $m+1$ times w.r.t. $t$ and put $t=0$. You get $1=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I do not think this argument works. When you multiply the sum (or the series) by $\cos kx$, the integral with $n=k$ is also equal to zero (the sines and the cosines are always orthogonal), so you conclude $0=0$. I noticed that the argument was wrong because you would be able to do the same starting with any even function, so you would have proven that the only even functions are the constants!

Comment: @GReyes You are right. Thank you for pointing out. The simplest proof I can now think of is the one I have posted now. I will see if I can come up with a real variable proof.

Comment: $e^{\cos{x}}$ has a taylor series with infinitely many terms, so I don't understand how you conclude it is a finite polynomial in $\cos{x}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are welcome. I like your new proof, but I think there must be a more elementary one. Thinking about it..

Comment: @vibe We are assuming that $e^{\cos x}$ is a finite linear combination of the functions $\cos (nx)$.  It is known that $\cos (nx)$ is a polynomial in $\cos x$.

Comment: @Edi I have added another proof which uses only basic calculus.

Comment: @GReyes I have added another proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  of differentiating both sides at the end, does it make sense if we expand $e^{\cos x} = \sum^\infty \frac{\cos^n x}{n!}$ and then subtract both sides by RHS such that we have $\sum^m_i b_i \cos^i x + \sum_m^\infty \frac{\cos^n x}{n!} = 0$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: You have to say why it is a contradiction. It requires a proof. @Edi

Comment: @Edi OK, fine. Expanding $e^{\cos x}$ is fine.

Comment: @Edi For every $t \in [-1,1]$ there exists a real number $x$ such that $\cos x=t$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I saw your proof, I think it is very elegant. I just added another proof, which I think it is interesting because it reveals a more general result. BTW the polynomials in your proof are just the Chebyshev polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier representation of a function is unique. It would suffice to show that all the Fourier coefficients are non-zero.

Indeed, the function $x\to e^{\cos x}$ is positive, even and **decreasing** on $[0,\pi]$. When we integrate such a function against $\cos kx$ to get the $k$-th coefficient, we get a positive result since the main contribution to the integral (on $[0,\pi]$) arises from the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2k}]$ which is the closest to zero. The negative contribution from $[\frac{\pi}{2k},\frac{\pi}{k} ]$  is smaller in absolute value, and the same happens with every pair of subsequent contiguous intervals, giving a positive outcome.

By uniqueness, you cannot represent the given function as a finite linear combination of the Fourier basis.

This argument actually shows that any function that is positive, decreasing on $[0,\pi]$ and even will require all the cosines of multiple arcs in their representation.